# If I have two UITableViews in a UIViewController how do I detect which tableview is scrolling?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have tableview1 and tableview2 in my `UIViewController`, both of them can be scrolled.

I implement these two methods in the UIViewController but seems when one tableview scrolls the other catches the event as well.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
       // Do something.
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Do something.
}
```

How do I know which tableview is being scrolled so I don't need to run extra code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` is inherited from `UIScrollView`, so the `(UIScrollView *)scrollView` parameter is the pointer to your scrolling `tableView`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (scrollView == tableview1 ) {
       // Do something 1.
    }
    else if (scrollView == tableview2 ) {
       // Do something 2.
    }
}
```